# Background-color lightning component

Tags: lightning, css

I am trying to set the background-color of my lightning component, I cant figure out what css I should use. By doing this:

```
.THIS {
  background-color: white; 
}
```

The larger part of the background becomes white, but the space between the footer stays the default color (greyish/blueish).

```
.THIS {
  background-color: white;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Makes the whole page white. Anyone an example? Thanks in advance

This is the code of the component:

```
    <c:Partners_Header stepnumber="{!v.stepnumber}" header="{!v.header}"/>

    <body>
        <div class="slds-container--center slds-container--large">
            <aura:if isTrue="{!v.stepnumber==1}">
                <c:B2B_Partners_Login labels="{!v.fieldLabels}" stepnumber="{!v.stepnumber}"/>
            </aura:if>
            <aura:if isTrue="{!v.stepnumber==2}">
                <c:B2B_Partners_Forgot_Password labels="{!v.fieldLabels}" />
            </aura:if>
        </div>
    </body>
    <!-- include footer -->
    <c:Partners_Footer/>
```

[image: Different background color]

Comment: If possible please post a screenshot of the issue marking the area you want to change the background.

Comment: @SarojBera Done

Comment: Can you please share the markup of your lightning component? It sounds like you have a css style referenced somewhere that you want to override.

Comment: @JannisBott Done

Comment: @Ant could you provide html part of your components ?
I help you but I need inspect html code in file :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to wrap your component content like this -

```
<aura:component>
  <div class="slds-box slds-theme_default">
     //your component content
  </div>
</aura:component>
```

then your component background would be default white. For more information - https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/themes/

or if you want some other background color then you have to write some css

```
.THIS .slds-theme_backgroundColor-lightblue {
    background-color: lightblue;
}
```

and add this class to your container div

```
<aura:component>
   <div class="slds-box slds-theme_default slds-theme_backgroundColor-lightblue">
         //your component content
   </div>
</aura:component>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="slds-container--center slds-container--large">
    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.stepnumber==1}">
        <c:B2B_Partners_Login labels="{!v.fieldLabels}" />
    </aura:if>
    <aura:if isTrue="{!v.stepnumber==2}">
        <c:B2B_Partners_Forgot_Password labels="{!v.fieldLabels}" />
    </aura:if>
</div>
```

Seems to be your top part. You could give this dive a specific class to set its background:

```
<div class="slds-container--center slds-container--large custom-background">
```

In your css class you can add this:

```
.THIS .custom-background {
    background-color: white;
}
```

This will set the background of your top part to white.

The footer seems to be its own component (Is assume that you meant c:Partners_Footer instead of c.Partners_Footer).

If that's the case, I would also add a css class in the footer component that sets its background to white.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help but this doesn't solve the problem. The space is still white with your solution. I assume because there is no html generated for it. So than another solution could be this:

Comment: I think you'll need to change your c:Partners_Footer component too. Can you post the markup of that one too?

Comment: <aura:component >
 <!-- The universal footer -->
 <div class="slds-container--center slds-container--medium">
  <div class="slds">
   <div class="slds-grid slds-grid_align-center">
    <div class="slds-docked-form-footer slds-has-divider--top">
......
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</aura:component>

Comment: The slds-has-divider--top adds the greyish line. If you remove this your problem should be solved.

Comment: The problem is not the line, I need it. The problem is the background color of the part above the line untill the login component starts (see picture)

Comment: Ok, I am bit lost. The space between footer and login component looks white to me according to your picture... Sorry that I can't help

Comment: It is a slight difference but it is a different color, assume I would want to make that space red. Would you know how?

Comment: Easiest is probably to just draw on your screenshot. Or you use inspect element in your browser to highlight it.

Comment: I drew on the screenshot to show what part of the screen has a different background-color. Hope this is clear for you.